# Chances of getting a B-2 visa if my partner has a working visa

Tags: usa, visa

Just wondering what you think my chances are of getting a B-2 Visa. My partner and I are Australian citizens, and he has recently got a job in USA and has a working visa.

We are planning on getting married, but that will not be before we leave Australia.

The ties I will have to Australia are family and a house. Is this enough to obtain a B-2 visa then change to a E3-D visa once we are married?

Comment: It can't be uncommon for a de facto partner to apply for a B-2 for that reason since [the requirements page for virtually every non-immigrant visa points to this as the (only) alternative to the dependent status you don't yet qualify for](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/au/au-niv-typee3.asp#dependants). That said, I have no idea what the documentation requirements are for that and, if no one else does either, you may be getting into "ask a lawyer" territory (e.g. the lawyer that helped with the E-3?).